# Larger memory footprint when using BitmapFactory.DecodeFile in C# (and huge memory for tiny image)

Tags: android, image, memory, bitmap, xamarin.android

I just want to see if anyone else has noticed that when loading images into memory, the exact same C# code uses more memory to hold the images (~1.5x the amount in Java).

This Java code results in a total memory size of **105.5 MB**:

```
Bitmap[] bitmaps = new Bitmap[100];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String imagePath = "/evolution/threesixty/216/Edaphosaurus_001.jpg";

    bitmaps[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(root + imagePath);
}
```

This C# code results in **148.1 MB**:

```
Bitmap[] bitmaps = new Bitmap[100];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    string root = Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
    string imagePath = "/evolution/threesixty/216/Edaphosaurus_001.jpg";

    bitmaps[i] = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(root + imagePath);
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why? I understand that the .NET wrappers may use a little more to hold extra binding data or things, but surely not that much?

*Also, as a side question:
Each image is only **60 KB** on disk, why is the in-memory version **1 MB**? I know that my loading method does not do any sampling/density checking, but that was not the aim. Surely loading a <100KB image should not exceed 100KB memory space?*

Here is the image I am using (994x748px @ 300dpi):

[image: the image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on replies from the Mono for Android mailing list:

> The images you are loading are jpg compressed. Bitmap is an
>   uncompressed format. A little Googling showed a typical JPEG
>   compression ratio of 10:1 to 20:1 without losing noticeable image
>   quality. 60KB -> 1 MB is in that range.

And another:

> Loading a bitmap into memory decompresses it and depending on what
>   bitmap config you load it with it will take up more memory than its
>   compressed size on disk.

After looking at this information on compression (I have no idea what went on in my head as I realize that compression makes the in-memory image smaller for saving and loading it will then decompress it into memory), I now understand how things work ;)
The image is decompressed to almost 2MB when saved as a bitmap - and if I look at the image properties in Irfanview.

So what I am doing now is setting the sample size to `2` and using the `Bitmap.Config.Rgb565`. This reduces the total images size to about 30 MB, which is way better. Although the quality is not as good, I can then load the higher resolution image when I need it and the user doesn't know.

Comment: Visit: http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Larger-memory-footprint-when-using-BitmapFactory-DecodeFile-in-C-and-huge-memory-for-tiny-image-td5710394.html;cid=1340028135060-792 for the mailing list thread.

Answer (score 4):

Your figure of 148.1 MB for 100 images is the exact figure I would expect for this. 994 x 748 gives 743,512 pixels; assuming you're using a format that uses 2 bytes per pixel (which is very low-quality for an image, FWIW - the RGB565 format should have been banned internationally decades ago), that gives you 1.481 MB per image. This is of course much larger than the image size on disk, because the image file is compressed.

I have no idea why the Java version of this would consume only 105.5 MB; there's no bitmap format that I know of that uses 1.333 bytes per pixel. Most likely you're reading the memory usage wrong, or else the Java runtime is caching some of the images to disk instead of keeping them in-memory.